# QEvent::KeyPress in QWidget doesn't emmit

Tags: c++, qt

I have two Widget.

I load my second widget to first, in this way:

```
 NumpadService *numpadService = new NumpadService(this);
 ui->pinpadLayout->addWidget(numpadService,0,0);
```

pinpadLayout it's just QGirdLayout.

NumberService widget has buttons like pinpad. I want to simulate key press to fill QEditLine that is property of first widget(not pinpad).

I tried in this way:

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent (QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier, "0");
    QCoreApplication::postEvent (this->parentWidget(), event);

   if (event->isAccepted()) {
       QMessageBox::information(this, "", "ok");

   } else {
       QMessageBox::information(this, "", "bad");

   }
```

It shows ok, but QLineEdit is still empty. I must use physical keyboard. I need to make it work with touch screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, QKeyEvent's accepted flag is set to true, so whether or not the event was handled by any widget, I believe you're going to get your "ok" message. From the code you've posted, it isn't possible to tell if your parentWidget is the correct receiver. I believe you might also have focus issues; the key event is going to go to the widget (under or at parentWidget) that currently has the focus. I'm not sure how much functionality your pinpad requires, but for simply adding characters, it seems like it might be easier to use the QLineEdit's "text" and "setText" methods.

Comment: I don't want to use setText, because I need to make my pinpad working on different QWidget, so I prefer simulate key press. I want to make it working on every field in QWidget.

Comment: That makes sense. You might try QCoreApplication::sendEvent instead of postEvent. Based on my reading, it appears to send directly to the receiver without going through the event queue, so I'm hopeful that will eliminate any issues with which widget has keyboard focus.